# How to Efficiently Convert a Markdown Table to a DataFrame in Python?

Tags: python, nlp, markdown

I need to convert a markdown table into a pandas DataFrame. I've managed to do this using the `pd.read_csv` function with '|' as the separator, but it seems like there's some additional cleanup required. Specifically, I need to remove the row containing '-----', which is used for table separation, and I also want to get rid of the last column.

Here's a simplified example of what I'm doing:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# The text containing the table
text = """
| Some Title | Some Description             | Some Number |
|------------|------------------------------|-------------|
| Dark Souls | This is a fun game           | 5           |
| Bloodborne | This one is even better      | 2           |
| Sekiro     | This one is also pretty good | 110101      |
"""

# Use StringIO to create a file-like object from the text
text_file = StringIO(text)

# Read the table using pandas read_csv with '|' as the separator
df = pd.read_csv(text_file, sep='|', skipinitialspace=True)

# Remove leading/trailing whitespace from column names
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()

# Remove the index column
df = df.iloc[:, 1:]
```

Is there a more elegant and efficient way to convert a markdown table into a DataFrame without needing to perform these additional cleanup steps? I'd appreciate any suggestions or insights on improving this process.

Comment: regex probably..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```
import re
import pandas as pd

text = """
| Some Title | Some Description             | Some Number |
|------------|------------------------------|-------------|  
| Dark Souls | This is a fun game           | 5           |
| Bloodborne | This one is even better      | 2           |
| Sekiro     | This one is also pretty good | 110101      |
"""

pattern = r"\| ([\w\s]+) \| ([\w\s]+) \| ([\w\s]+) \|"

# Use the findall function to extract all rows that match the pattern
matches = re.findall(pattern, text)

# Extract the header and data rows
header = matches[0]
data = matches[1:]

# Create a pandas DataFrame using the extracted header and data rows
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)

# Optionally, convert numerical columns to appropriate types
df['Some Number'] = df['Some Number'].astype(int)

print(df)
```

Comment: i like this method, so i added the imports and the text.  nice work.

Comment: what if we don't know the number of columns?

Comment: the other method is independent of the number of columns, but you can count to columns based on `|`.

Answer (score 0):

this will work. Also it does not require the `import io` line.

Another method was proposed which uses the `re` module which is a nice alternative too. So you have 2 methods.

```py
import pandas as pd

text = """
| Some Title | Some Description             | Some Number |
|------------|------------------------------|-------------|  
| Dark Souls | This is a fun game           | 5           |
| Bloodborne | This one is even better      | 2           |
| Sekiro     | This one is also pretty good | 110101      |
"""

lines = text.split("\n")
header = lines[1].strip("|").split("|")

data = [] 

# Loop through lines starting from 2
for line in lines[2:]:
    
    # Break once we hit an empty line
    if not line.strip():
        break
        
    cols = line.strip("|").split("|")
    row = dict(zip(header, cols))
    data.append(row)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

which will produce this:

```
    Some Title    Some Description                Some Number 
0  ------------  ------------------------------  -------------
1   Dark Souls    This is a fun game              5           
2   Bloodborne    This one is even better         2           
3   Sekiro        This one is also pretty good    110101
```

Comment: what if we don't know the number of columns?

Comment: then you could count the number of `|` in the top row and subtract 1. This would be a simple method for obtaining the number of columns...

Comment: like this: `num_columns = top_row.count('|') - 1`

Comment: This method is agnostic to the number of columns since it splits using `|` already....