Reading a table from a txt file in pandas
It is not possible to display the table correctly
┌───────────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬──────────┬──────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│          Library          │    Vulnerability    │ Severity │    Status    │           Installed Version            │      Fixed Version      │                            Title                             │
├───────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────┼──────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ apt                       │ CVE-2011-3374       │ LOW      │ affected     │ 1.8.2.3+ci202206080010+linux           │                         │ It was found, do not                                         │
│                           │                     │          │              │                                        │                         │ correctly...                                                 │
│                           │                     │          │              │                                        │                         │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2011-3374                    │
├───────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤          │              ├────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ bash                      │ CVE-2019-18276      │          │              │ 1.0-2.linux                            │                         │ bash: when effective                                  the... │
│                           │                     │          │              │                                        │                         │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2019-18276                   │
│                           ├─────────────────────┤          │              │                                        ├─────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│                           │ TEMP-0841856-B18BAF │          │              │                                        │                         │ [Privilege  ]                                                │
│                           │                     │          │              │                                        │                         │ https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/TEMP-0841856-B1- │
│                           │                     │          │              │                                        │                         │ 8BAF                                                         │
├───────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤          │              ├────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ binutils                  │ CVE-2017-13716      │          │              │ 2.31.1-16+ci202206301611+linux         │                         │ binutils: Memory demangler routine                           │
│                           │                     │          │              │                                        │                         │ in libiberty                                                 │
│                           │                     │          │              │                                        │                         │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2017-13716                   │
│                           ├─────────────────────┤          │              │                                        ├─────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│                           │ CVE-2018-1000876    │          │              │                                        │                         │  leads to heap-based buffer                                  │
│                           │                     │          │              │                                        │                         │ overflow in objdump                                          │
│                           │                     │          │              │                                        │                         │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2018-1000876                 │
│                           ├─────────────────────┤          │              │                                        ├─────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤

data=pd.read_csv('/data.txt', sep='|', skiprows=[1], names = ['Library', 'Vulnerability', 'Severity', 'Status', 'Installed Version', 'Fixed Version', 'Title'], encoding='utf-8')
data.head(10)


This is not a CSV file. Does not look like any file that pandas could read natively. You might need to write custom function to preprocess the file before you can read it in as a dataframe. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/77068592

This code solves the problem when creating a rolling row. As a new line is recognized, the rolling row is saved on a new flattened table.
Test Table
┌───────────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬──────────┬──────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│          Column1          │    Column2          │ Column3  │    Column4   │           Column5                      │      Column6            │                            Column7                           │
├───────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────┼──────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ app1                      │ COD-2011-3374       │ FQ1      │ state1       │ 1.8.2.3+ci202206080010+so              │                         │ Text                                                         │
│                           │                     │          │              │                                        │                         │ Text                                                         │
│                           │                     │          │              │                                        │                         │ Link                                                         │
├───────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤          │              ├────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ app2                      │ COD-2019-18276      │          │              │ 1.0-2.so                               │                         │ Text                               the Text...               │
│                           │                     │          │              │                                        │                         │ https://Text.Text.com/Text/Text                              │
│                           ├─────────────────────┤          │              │                                        ├─────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│                           │ COD-0841856-B18BAF  │          │              │                                        │                         │ [Text]                                                       │
│                           │                     │          │              │                                        │                         │ https://Text.com/Text                                        │
│                           │                     │          │              │                                        │                         │ Text                                                         │
├───────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤          │              ├────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤

Solution
import pandas as pd
import os

file_name='table_category'
module_dir = os.path.abspath("")
file1 = os.path.join(module_dir,str(file_name)+'.txt')
file1 = open(file1, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
lines = file1.readlines()

#columns
print(lines[1])
pre_columns = lines[1].split('│')
columns = [j.strip() for j in pre_columns][1:-1]
print('columns')
print(columns)

#rows
rolling_row = None
is_new_row = True
flatten_table = []
for line in lines[3:]:
    if('─' in line):
        is_new_row = True
        #next rows is a new line so save rolling row as new row
        flatten_table.append(rolling_row.copy())
        continue

    #clear current row
    current_row = line.split('│')
    current_row = [j.strip() for j in current_row][1:-1]
    
    if not rolling_row :
        rolling_row = current_row

    if(is_new_row):
        #take current row values to a new rolling row, but only if currrent row have values
        for i in range(len(current_row)):
            if(current_row[i] and current_row[i] != ''):
                rolling_row[i] = current_row[i]
    else:
        #append non empty values to rolling row
        for i in range(len(current_row)):
            if(current_row[i] and current_row[i] != ''):
                rolling_row[i] += "\n"+current_row[i]
    is_new_row = False
print('flatted table')
print(flatten_table)

df_flatted_table = pd.DataFrame(flatten_table, columns=columns)
df_flatted_table.head()

Output

